# Display nothing when I import .DAE file from blender 2.5 to Papervision 3D 2.1 why?

Tags: flash, 3d, blender, papervision3d

I have created a cube and applied materials and texture in blender (2.5). But when I import that model to Papervision 3d (2.1), I don't see anything - just a blank screen. On the other hand, if I use any other .dae model(for example, I am referring Papervision3D Essentials book, so I used those samples) then I can see the model. What's the problem? Why is the model that I exported from blender not working?

Here is my script:

```
package {

    import flash.events.Event;

    import org.papervision3d.events.FileLoadEvent;
    import org.papervision3d.events.InteractiveScene3DEvent;
    import org.papervision3d.materials.BitmapMaterial;
    import org.papervision3d.materials.ColorMaterial;
    import org.papervision3d.materials.utils.MaterialsList;
    import org.papervision3d.objects.DisplayObject3D;
    import org.papervision3d.objects.parsers.DAE;
    import org.papervision3d.view.BasicView;
    import org.papervision3d.objects.parsers.Collada;

    public class modelTest extends BasicView
    {
        private var model:DisplayObject3D;
        private var distance:Number = 1000;
        private var speed:Number = 0.2;
        private var rangeX:Number = 0.02;
        private var rangeY:Number = 0.02;
        private var rangeZ:Number = 0.05;
        private var targetRotationX:Number = 0;

        public function modelTest()
        {   
            stage.frameRate = 40;

            init();
            startRendering();
        }

        private function init():void
        {
            model = new DAE();
            DAE(model).load("assets/cube.dae");
            scene.addChild(model);

            viewport.interactive = true;
            model.addEventListener(FileLoadEvent.LOAD_COMPLETE, modelLoaded);
        }

        private function modelLoaded(e:FileLoadEvent):void
        {
            trace("Used materials by this model: " + model.materials);
            true).addEventListener(InteractiveScene3DEvent.OBJECT_CLICK, click);
        }


        override protected function onRenderTick(e:Event=null):void
        {   
            super.onRenderTick();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the output:

```
INFO: Papervision3D 2.1 rev920 (August 11th, 2009)

INFO: Viewport autoScaleToStage : Papervision has changed the Stage scale mode. 
INFO: DisplayObject3D: COLLADA_Scene 
INFO: DisplayObject3D: Cube 
INFO: DisplayObject3D: Lamp 
INFO: DisplayObject3D: Camera 
Used materials by this model: Material_001-material
```

Blender file : http://imageedit.netai.net/cube.blend

DAE file : http://imageedit.netai.net/cube.dae

Answer (score 0):

PV3D hasn't been kept up-to-date, if you're looking to take advantage of Stage3D (Flash GPU acceleration for 3d scenes), you'll want to try Away3D or some of the other engines instead.

That being said, it's been a while since I've touched the PV3D stuff, but I remember I had to be very specific in how my Collada geometry was written - the parser in Papervision3D only reads a subset of the spec (if it tried to read the full spec, the parser would be enormous - part of why Away3d does not support it)

A search for "Collada blender export for Papervision" shows me some helpful posts on the web, eg:

http://osflash.org/pipermail/papervision3d_osflash.org/2007-February/001726.html

Tells us that your Collada export has to have triangles.

Or, you could dig into the Collada Parser and figure out what it's looking for - you'll see that the loader is only looking for triangles, and only in a specific spot in the XML.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Yes I am thinking to switch to Away 3D. Actually, I am expecting best quality, becaz I am not going to do animation just going to show the 3D model. But I experienced that the Papervision 3D is not good for expose 3D though, whatever I am exporting as DAE from 3DS MAX, I can see the model with very quality less in PV3D. So do you thing, Away 3D will solve my problem? THanks

Comment: If you mean that your DAE isn't loading, then no, because the latest version of Away3D hasn't added Collada support yet.  Your best chance is to look at the file formats that Away3D does support and export to one of those from Max.  This thread talks about exporting from Max to MD5, which Away3D can read:  http://away3d.com/forum/viewthread/1295/#4262

Comment: Away3D reads Collada. A Blender3D export of Collada can be imported using `_loader = new Loader3D(); _loader.loadData(new SomeColladaModelClass(), assetLoaderContext); _loader.addEventListener(AssetEvent.ASSET_COMPLETE, assetCompleteHnd); _view.scene.addChild(_loader);` This is a quick and dirty test derived from the example file "Basic_Load3DS.as" that Away3D provides.  Just replace all the 3DS file references with your Collada file.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks.  Are you checking it out from the repository, and is it in the fp11 src?  I'm still not seeing either a Collada or DAE parser in the loaders, just assumed it wasn't there yet (maybe it's new?).

Comment: I generally only use standard public download methods for all my code, for various reasons.  I am referencing the "Gold" download from the Away3D website.  The Collada parser is `away3d.loaders.parsers.DAEParser`.  You can activate it by `AssetLibrary.enableParser(DAEParser);`,  or else activate all parsers using `Parsers.enableAllBundled();`.